# python Scikit-learn как правильно смоделировать задачу классификации (Random forest)

Tags: python, dataframe, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn

Есть такой dataframe:

| index | razryad | age | salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 22 | 30000 |
| 2 | 3 | 19 | 36000 |
| 3 | 4 | 30 | 40000 |
| 4 | 5 | 25 | 47000 |

Коротко: таблица содержит уровень зарплаты, где есть зависимость чем выше разряд тем выше зарплата. У меня же почему то вес признака "age" решает большую роль при предсказании, чем признак разряд. Проблема звучит так при вводе новых данных (разряд = 4, возраст = 17) выдает предсказание равной = 36000, хотя по идее тут есть зависимость от разряда, но модель почему то считает вес "age" больше "razryad" ???  Или возможно я не корректно строю модель либо нужно самому увеличить вес "razryad" ? хотя по идее модель сама должна найти такую зависимость от разряда

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier 

df_json = pd.read_json('dataframes//test_data.json')
X_test = df_json[['razryad', 'age']].reset_index(drop=True)    # 
y_test = df_json['salary']         #

model = RandomForestClassifier()    # выбираем модель обучения: Случайный лес класссификация
model.fit(X_test, y_test) # обучаем модель

# подаем новые данные для выдачи прогноза ожидаемой зарплаты
example_test = {'razryad': [4], 'age': [11]}

example_df_test = pd.DataFrame(example_test)
res = model.predict(example_df_test)    # предсказывает данные
print(f"\nПредсказанные данные:\n{res=}")
```

[image: вес признаков при прогнозировании]

Comment: Предоставьте данные в воспроизводимом виде. Например, в виде файла, который можно скачать. Либо, если их немного, прямо в виде текста `json` для загрузки.

Comment: А вообще если данных мало и вы взяли сложную модель, то эта модель будет склонна к **переобучению**, у неё будет плохо с **генерализацией**. Лучше брать модели попроще для начала - линейную регрессию, например.

Comment: Спасибо вас понял только начал изучать машинное обучение )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых модели для классификации не умеют интерполировать. Они выдают одно из значений, которые есть в обучающей выборке. И вы ещё и даёте на вход значение `age`, которого не было в обучении. При этом модель вы взяли слишком сложную, склонную к переобучению. Если взять простую модель, причём регрессии, а не классификации, то всё будет гораздо логичнее.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

model = LinearRegression()
```

Вывод:

```
Предсказанные данные (я округляю всё до целых значений здесь и далее):
43434
```

Коэффициенты модели:

```
print(int(model.intercept_), list(map(int,model.coef_)))
```

Вывод:

```
21956 [5847, -173]
```

Т.е. формула расчёта у линейной модели получилась такая:

```
salary = 21956 + razryad * 5847 - 173 * age
```

Т.е. чем **меньше возраст**, тем **зарплата больше**. Таковы ваши данные, если вы на них внимательно посмотрите, переходы между разрядами 2 и 3 и 4 и 5 сопровождаются именно падением возраста.